# debugging ZEXP import - no module named

Tags: plone

I am attempting to zexp import a site from what should have been the same Plone version and addon packages. However, when I do so I get

```
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 60, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 620, in manage_importObject
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 638, in _importObjectFromFile
  Module ZODB.ExportImport, line 92, in importFile
  Module transaction._transaction, line 260, in savepoint
  Module transaction._transaction, line 257, in savepoint
  Module transaction._transaction, line 690, in __init__
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 1123, in savepoint
  Module ZODB.Connection, line 587, in _commit
  Module ZODB.ExportImport, line 176, in _importDuringCommit
  ImportError: No module named MyOldPackage.Content
```

This is an old Archetypes class that has since been migrated to a replacement in Dexterity. I thought I had removed all references but apparently something got missed. I get that I have to remove all objects that use this class but there's the rub - how do I find which objects use them?

I thought I had found something in the CMFEditions tools but that might be a red herring. Trying to export portal_historiesstorage yields the same error so I thought perhaps some old versions of past content were stuck there. Deleted shadow storage and rebuilt it, so it's now blank (ZMI page confirms this). But I'm still getting the error when trying to import just this tool - how is it still trying to reference this class? This is why I think it might be a red herring and it's inheriting something from the portal object, but I'm having a rough time trying to find where this class is referenced.

edit:
It looks like I have something bad in zvc_repo - I'm not sure the difference in what shadow storage and this are supposed to do. Here's a proposed script. Can anyone with better CMFEditions or ZopeVersionControl comment on how this sounds?

```
tool = portal.portal_historiesstorage
from ZODB.broken import PersistentBroken

bad_repo_ids = set()
for sequence in tool.zvc_repo._histories:
    for version in tool.zvc_repo[sequence]._versions:
        obj = tool.zvc_repo[sequence].getVersionById(version)._data._object.object
        if isinstance(obj, PersistentBroken):
            bad_repo_ids.add(sequence)

for bid in bad_repo_ids:
    del tool.zvc_repo._histories[bid]
```

Comment: As a side note, the XML export format can be useful for checking where the class lurks.

Comment: Kind of looks okay, but I don't usually delve this deep into the histories.

Comment: But maybe this script for cleaning the history helps you: https://github.com/collective/plone_clean_history

Comment: Hi, didn't read this in depth, but for finding broken objects, this script might help: https://github.com/ida/skriptz/blob/master/py/plone/find_catalogued_broken_objs.py